# Shell: Is it possible to enter input to an interactive command inside the shell?

Tags: shell

It doesn't work for me.
e.g.  Entering a command `read -r value` in a terminal would wait for an input from the user, and after user enters some value, we can see that value with `echo $value`. But is something like that is even possible in a shell (not term).

I can do that in term, but shell is more convenient in terms of keystrokes.

Edit: Let me elaborate a little.In `M-x shell`, i do this

```
$ read -r some_value <RET>
abcd <RET>

Command 'abcd' not found.
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this with `emacs -Q`, even with bash and `. /etc/bash_completion`. It might be due to something else in your Emacs configuration or in your bash configuration.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' "emacs-bash-completion" package in MELPA was the culprit and not "bash_completion